# TikZ node positioning in Beamer ignores x coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, positioning, nodes

I have the following `frame` in `beamer`:

```
\begin{frame}{Language}
\begin{block}{}
    \begin{align*}
    \onslide<1->{
        &\text{Types} & T &::= B | T \to T \\
    }
    \onslide<2->{    
        &\text{Terms} & E &::= A | E\ E | \ldots |
        \tikz[baseline]{
            \node (term-mon) [anchor=base,fill=blue!20]
            {$\mathsf{mon}^{f, g}_h(E)$};
        }
        \onslide<3> {
            \tikz[baseline]\node [fill=blue!20] (term-mon-expl) at ($(term-mon) + (1,2)$)
            {Comments};
        }
    }    
    \end{align*}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
```

Basically, I want to highlight a part of the formula and display an additional node nearby on the next slide. However, for some reason TikZ ignores my 1cm shift towards x-axis and only shifts the `term-mon-expl` node towards y-axis, placing it right next to the `term-mon` node. Why?

Comment: You need to have either the nodes in one TikZ picture or to use the 'remember picture'/'overlay' combo.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks, I forgot about `overlay`. You can post it as an answer, so that I could accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code shows to possibilities to use two nodes that should be placed relative to each other

- in one TikZ picture with
- with the `remember picture`-`overlay` combo.

### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{align*}
    & \text{Types} & T & ::= B | T \to T \\
   \onslide<2->{
    & \text{Terms} & E &::= A | E\ E | \ldots |
      \tikz[
        baseline=(term-mon.base),
        nodes={fill=blue!20}] {
          \node    (term-mon)                                    {$\mathsf{mon}^{f, g}_h(E)$};
          \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
          \node<3> (term-mon-expl) at ([shift={(1,2)}] term-mon) {Comments};
          \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
       }
   }
  \end{align*}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{align*}
   & \text{Types} & T & ::= B | T \to T \\
  \onslide<2->{
   & \text{Terms} & E &::= A | E\ E | \ldots |
     \tikz[baseline,remember picture]
       \node (term-mon) [anchor=base,fill=blue!20] {$\mathsf{mon}^{f, g}_h(E)$};
  }
  \onslide<3> {
     \tikz[baseline,remember picture,overlay]
       \node [fill=blue!20] (term-mon-expl) at ($(term-mon) + (1,2)$) {Comments};
  }
  \end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]